# MySQL fails to return items with AES_ENCRYPT function

Tags: mysql, aes

I added an item with the following SQL sentence:

```
INSERT INTO `db`.`users` (`name`, `pass`) VALUES ('Terry', AES_ENCRYPT('32145', '32145'))
```

Then the new line was added into the table, for sure.

When I tried to find this item with 'name' and 'pass',an empty set was returned. The query sentence is below:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` ='Terry' AND `pass`= AES_ENCRYPT('32145', '32145')
```

Is there anything wrong with the function AES_ENCRYPT? :-(

Updates in Apr 27th, 2014:

The type of "pass" was defined as `varchar(255)`, which turned out to be a disaster. :-(

After I modified its type as `varbinary(255)`, everything worked.

The original problem has been solve. But, why did type `varchar(255)` fail in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d359e/3) and the aes_encrypt [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt).

What type is your `pass` column? on the fiddle I defined it like:

```
pass varbinary(200)
```

Did this insert successfully:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, pass) VALUES ('Terry', aes_encrypt('32145', '32145'))
```

Then queried it like this:

```
select * 
from users 
where name = 'Terry' and pass = aes_encrypt('32145', '32145');

select *, aes_decrypt(pass, '32145') 
from users 
where pass = aes_encrypt('32145', '32145');
```

So your query should have worked.

Comment: I defined the type of `pass` as `varchar(255)`, which caused the failure. After I modified its type as `varbinary(255)`, everything worked correctly. The insertion and queries are all correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name ='Terry' AND pass= AES_DECRYPT('32145', '32145')
```

[MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt)